# Language independent software libraries

Tags: programming-languages, formal-methods, typing

When trying to decide on the choice of a programming language for a
specific task, people will often tell me: "use this language because it
has the best library for the type of problems you are addressing".

I would rather choose my language for its intrinsic qualities as a
programming medium. That implies that libraries should be more
universally usable.

What work has there been to create programming libraries that could be
programmed and used in different languages, being mechanically adapted
from one to the other on the basis of a standardized interface
language/formalism (or any other mean)? How succesful has it been?

For example, I found one system that claims to do that : [Microsoft's .NET
Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx).
They say it is based on a Common Language Specification (CLS) which is defined in the [ECMA-335 Standard: Common Language Infrastructure](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Are there others? What about free-software frameworks?

Pointers to relevant papers or web sites are an answer. A survey would
be best.

**Note** (June 7, 2013): this question is more controversial than is visible.
However, I cannot fathom the nature of the controversy. Some people
support the question and/or make cogent comments. But the people who
seem unhappy about it just downvote without a word of explanation. I
am sure they have a good reason to do so. But it would better help our
understanding of the issues, or possibly of the lack of issues, if
they were a little more explicit as to what irks them.

Comment: To me, this seems difficult, as a library is often written in the language being used, thus tying the library to the "intrinsic qualities as a programming medium." You're best bet for something of this type is probably the idea of a Foreign Function Interface (FFI), which allows a library/program to be written in one language but called by another.

Comment: To make stuff written for e.g. FORTRAN work nicely with the concepts/idioms of a different language, like Pyton, is a _huge_ task. The "this is designed for/writtin in <foo>" will show through. Besides, Java is a nice counterexample: It is a _terrible_ language, but there is so much in terms of libraries and assorted programming tools (required because, hum, the language sucks _hard_) that people turn out much more productive in it than in alternatives. I'd suspect the whole .NET is just smoke blowing in the wind, the system is just too new for a sizeable set of stuff to accrue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Java Bytecode

Similar to Microsoft's CLS, the [Java Bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) that the [Java virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) executes gives you the (theoretical) possibility of using libraries from one JVM-targeting language with another JVM-targeting language. For example, Java libraries can be used in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), which IMO is a much better language than Java itself. Libraries written in Scala could be used in [Clojure](http://clojure.org/), or in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), or in one of [these languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages).

However, although interoperability is theoretically possible because of the common byte code to which all these languages compile, it is said (my personal experience is fairly limited) to sometimes be complicated to actually get it working.

Another, in the context of your question probably equally big drawback is, that using libraries from other languages often forces you to program in that languages style - and consequently "rip" you out of the style of the language you are actually programming in. For example, due to the lack of closures/anonymous functions and higher-order functions, Java libraries often don't have "nice" interfaces in the functional programming sense. Scala libraries, on the other hand, are usually written in a functional way.

#### Multi-platform languages

Another way of addressing your problem are multi-platform languages such as [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).

> Haxe can be compiled to all popular programming platforms with its
>   fast compiler – JavaScript, Flash, NekoVM, PHP, C++, C# and Java
>   (soon).

To be fair, I don't have any experience with Haxe, so all I can do is conjecture. That said, I see this approach as a double-edged sword. On the one hand, it allows you to implement libraries only once and then compile them to C++, PHP, etc., and use them from their. On the other hand, if you write a client or a library depending on other libraries in Haxe, you are probably limited to Haxe libraries, and, for example, cannot use the highly appraised C++ library [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

A similar, although assumably less powerful approach is followed by [Apache Thrift](https://projects.apache.org/projects/thrift.html).

> Apache Thrift allows you to define data types and service interfaces
>   in a simple definition file. Taking that file as input, the compiler
>   generates code to be used to easily build RPC clients and servers that
>   communicate seamlessly across programming languages. Instead of
>   writing a load of boilerplate code to serialize and transport your
>   objects and invoke remote methods, you can get right down to business.

#### General worries

I assume that the "out of style" problem mentioned in the context of JVM-targeting languages is actually more general and probably something that makes it difficult to truly achieve what you want. If you specify interfaces arbitrarily general, it is likely that they feel out of place when used in any concrete programming language.

A second problem related to interfaces is which data structures to use as input/output data structures. For example, which data structures should a language-independent sorting library accept and return - arrays, sequences, lists, vectors, streams? And how are these mapped from/to data structures that actually exist in a given concrete language?

Another general problem I can see is performance. A library that is implemented in one language and cross-compiled into another is probably of poorer performance than one that is directly implemented in that language - which is not automatically a problem, but can definitely sometimes be one.

Comment: Thoughtful answer. Your remark on bytecode is interesting. But a
virtual machine is still a machine. The X86 is also a machine
providing a common code for many languages. What makes you think that
code compiled to bytecode is easier to share than, for example, X86
code ?  A possible answer that I see is that byte code is higher
level. Could we envision then a bunch of higher level constructs
that would be used to compile libraries, or to compile exportable
versions of libraries.

Comment: @babou Good question. It is probably less the technical aspect of sharing the library once it has been compiled to a common low-level language, but rather, how to share the high-level interface of the source library. For example, although a Java library that I use from Scala comes as a jar-file, i.e., as byte code, I am still able to use its Java interfaces. I am not actually sure how that matching between interfaces and byte code is done when multiple JVM-languages are involved, but it somehow is possible. Maybe that's what actually sets JVM code apart from native machine code.